# How to show data from first activity to another activity or fragment?

Tags: android, authentication, google-account, user-data, google-play-services

I created an application for a user login using a Google account. I included a log in button in an activity that is MainActivity. Everything went smoothly if I display data that has been obtained from the user to display in MainActivity.

#### MainActiviy.java:

`import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener  {
    static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 12345; //semacam kunci
    SignInButton signInButton;
    Button btnOut,btnRevoke;
    RelativeLayout lProfil;
    TextView txNama,txEmail;
    ImageView imgProfile;
    String nama,email,url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestId()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        lProfil=findViewById(R.id.lprofil);
        btnOut=findViewById(R.id.btn_signout);
        btnOut.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnRevoke=findViewById(R.id.btn_revoke);
        btnRevoke.setOnClickListener(this);

        txNama=findViewById(R.id.tx_nama);
        txEmail=findViewById(R.id.tx_email);
        imgProfile=findViewById(R.id.im_user);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }


    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    private void signOut() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        updateUI(false);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void revokeAccess() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        updateUI(false);
                    }
                });
    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d("RESPON", "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {

            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            Log.e("SUKSES", "display name: " + acct.getDisplayName());
             nama= acct.getDisplayName().toString();
             email = acct.getEmail().toString();
            if (acct.getPhotoUrl() !=null){
               url  = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            }


            txNama.setText(nama);
            txEmail.setText(email);
            Picasso.with(this)
                    .load(url)
                    .into(imgProfile);
            updateUI(true);
        } else {
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                signIn();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_signout:
                signOut();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_revoke:
                revokeAccess();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
    private void updateUI(final boolean isSignedIn) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (isSignedIn) {
                    signInButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnRevoke.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    lProfil.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    signInButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnRevoke.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    lProfil.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Call GoogleApiClient connection when starting the Activity
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
        if (account !=null) {
            updateUI(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Disconnect GoogleApiClient when stopping Activity
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

}`

But the problem is that I need to display user data in other activity/fragment when the user logins in MainActivity.

**How can I show user data that has been obtained from another activity?**

Comment: Duplicate possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application

Answer (score 0):

**In your `MainActivity` set data via `Intent`:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("DATA_NAME", data);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Access the data on `SecondActivity` as below:**

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("DATA_NAME");
```